# Python watchdog script doesn't function properly

Tags: python

I am trying to use Python Watchdog to monitor a directory for changes. However, when I try to run the Quickstart example:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = LoggingEventHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='.', recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

by putting in it the file **test.py**, nothing displays in the Terminal window where I ran it. What is causing this to happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you making changes in the directory?

Comment: Yes. I have tried making several changes, including creating and deleting a folder, and creating and deleting a file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the example on github: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog

This example seems to work as opposed to the one on the docs site that does not.

Comment: Thank you. I tied the example on Github, and it worked. However, it doesn't seem to detect file or folder deletion.

Comment: What happens - do you see any errors?

This runs OK for me. Are you running it with an argument to point it at a directory? For example: **`python watch.py "foo"`**? If I do that using: **`python watch.py "."`** then it watches the current directory no problem, and displays messages in the console on any file (including creation and deletion of both files and folders).

Comment: I have been running the script with an argument to potnt to a directory. The script prints out file and folder creation events, but it still doesn't print out deletion events.